# Perfect arc path in After Effects

Tags: path, animation, adobe-after-effects, bezier-curve

I'm trying to make an animation following [Material Design guidelines](https://material.google.com/motion/movement.html). Any way to make a perfect arc between two keyframes? I'm stuck on that, because doing it manually doesn't keep bezier handles straight in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with an expression, but the simplest way would probably be to just rotate around a point (Like if you attach a ball to a pole and swing around).

You could simply use the Anchor point tool to move the `Anchor point` outside of the circle and animate 90 degrees of rotation, but if you want some actual precision, like if it should align with other objects precisely, you should probably do it with a `null object` as the parent of the `circle` and rotate the `null` instead. That way you can align the `null` with the `circle` object pretty effortlessly

[image]

I made a null that I aligned with the circle and made the null parent to the circle. Then I animated the null with a 2 keyframe rotation animation from 0 degrees to -90.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I figured that but using anchor point instead, thank you!